# Default font color of richtext control

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, react, rich-text

Is it possible to set the default color of a Richtext React control element?
I'm trying to make my webpart responsive to the section background color.

It's possible to give the richtext element its own class but I can't get it to respond to setting the color property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out a workaround using a jQuery function that's called 'when needed':

```
export function SetRichtextDefaultColor(color : string){

    $(".ql-editor").children("p").css("color", color);  

}
```

a little more spohisticated, to make sure the background color is reflected on all editors correctly:

```
    $('.ql-editor').each(function(){

    var col = $(this).closest('.answer').css("color");
    $(this).children("p").css("color", col);

});
```